# How does phpMyAdmin show a date/time picker?

Tags: php, datepicker, phpmyadmin

Can anyone tell me how phpMyAdmin displays the date and time picker?

Revised Question:
I'm just clarifying my question that when you want to insert DATETIME value in any record that is being manually inserted by user, there comes a pop up asking you to choose your date and time with the help of jquery slider, what kind of plugin they use for that and where I can find it??
Hope it is clear now

Comment: Using JavaScript, most probably. Is this even a question? Well, it's got a `?` in it, so I suppose so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin uses it own coded calender which could be found at:

```
 http:/SERVERADDRESS/phpmyadmin/calendar.php
```

Comment: I cannot find any type of calendar.php script there

Comment: @HammadAsif: You took so long to find the script, more than an year, may be its gone now..

Comment: My account was blocked and has been re-opened few days back. That's why I am late.